# Durandaljs: how to filter ko.observablearray

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, single-page-application, durandal

i'm new to durundaljs

i wanted to know how can i filter an ko.observablearray

> define(['services/logger', 'data/data', 'functions/func'], function (logger, data, func) {
>   var vm = {
>   list: ko.observableArray([])
>   };
>   return vm;
>   });

i want to filter an item inside the list and display it in a table

thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Knockout has utility functions which are not documented but they exist w/in the library to help with filtering arrays.

Here is a complete list of all the utility methods for handling arrays:

```
ko.utils.arrayFilter
ko.utils.arrayFirst
ko.utils.arrayForEach
ko.utils.arrayIndexOf
ko.utils.arrayMap
ko.utils.arrayPushAll
ko.utils.arrayRemoveItem
ko.utils.compareArrays
ko.utils.unwrapObservable
```

and Ryan Niemeyer has written a nice [blog post](http://www.knockmeout.net/2011/04/utility-functions-in-knockoutjs.html) about how to use a few of them.

---

## Method 1

Here is a quick example to get your started:

```
var newList = ko.utils.arrayFilter(list(), function(item) {
   return item.price > 10;
});
```

This creates a `newList` of items which have a price over 10.
Then you can change your current list by passing it the new list:

```
list(newList);
```

---

## Method 2

Another option is to find the items you want to remove. Say you want to remove all items with a price over 10:

```
var rList = ko.utils.arrayFilter(list(), function(item) {
   return item.price > 10;
});
```

Next you can call:

```
list.removeAll(rList);
```

---

## Method 3

And as they say there is more than one way to metaphorically skin a cat:

```
list.remove(function(item) { return item.price > 10 });
```

---

## There you have it..

and I'm sure there are many more ways it can be done.  If you need some more advanced ways of filtering arrays, I would recommend looking at [underscore.js](http://underscorejs.org/)